# How to clear a map with map in it?

Tags: c++

```
map<int, map<int, vector<string> > > test;
// some statement to assign values to test
test.clear();
```

Is above enough to release all memory used by test or I have to iterate the map to release the inner map and vector one by one?

Comment: Wait, no, I misread the question :(  This isn't a dupe of that....  Oops.

Comment: The library was not designed by idiots, of course you don't need to free every element one-by-one. Do you expect to have to free every `char` in every `string` too?

Comment: Why have I seen three people lately all trying to call `clear()` on standard containers to free memory before they go out of scope?

Comment: If you don't allocate memory, you don't need to worry about deallocating it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your code is sufficient to clear the inner maps and the vectors they contain. Destructors of the containers will take care of clearing out the resources held in keys and values of the maps. Of course the emptied map itself will not be deallocated until it gets destroyed, either by going out of scope or by virtue of its owner object being deleted.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight. I intend to keep the empty map since what I want to do is just to refresh its content.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to free all memory allocated by all sub containers. It is true for all STL containers.